# The data from Firestore database won't read back to the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want the data from firestore database to display on the page. I can post the data to the firestore database just fine, but when i tried to displaying it, it won't read back to display on the app. It will just appear as no data. What am i missing?

This is my code.First one is the page which i post the data to the firestore and displaying data on the samepage. The second one contains post and read function that connect to firestore.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'database/firestore.dart';
import 'my_post_button.dart';
import 'my_textfield.dart';


class ItemPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ItemPage({super.key});

  //Firestore access
  final FirestoreDatabase database = FirestoreDatabase();

  //text controller
  final TextEditingController newPostController = TextEditingController();

  //post message
  void postMessage() {
    if (newPostController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      String message = newPostController.text;
      database.addPost(message);
    }

    newPostController.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Items"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: MyTextField(
                      hintText: "Description and Location of your findings",
                      controller: newPostController),
                ),

                //Post button
                PostButton(
                  onTap: postMessage,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: database.getPostsStream(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              //show loading circle
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }

              //get all posts
              final posts = snapshot.data!.docs;

              //if no data
              if (snapshot.data == null || posts.isEmpty) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                    child: Text("No lost item at the moment"),
                  ),
                );
              }

              //return as a list
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: posts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    
                    //get each individual post
                    final post = posts[index];

                    //get data from each post
                    String message = post['Message'];
                    
                    //return as list tile
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text(message),
                    );
                 }
                )
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FirestoreDatabase {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  final CollectionReference posts =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Posts');

  

  //Post
  Future<void> addPost(String message) {
    return posts.add({
      'Message': message,
      'Timestamp': Timestamp.now(),
    });
  }

  //Read
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getPostsStream() {
    final postsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Posts')
        .orderBy('TimeStamp', descending: true)
        .snapshots();

    return postsStream;
  }
}
```

[image: My firestore database]

Comment: Hmm... the code looks fine at first glance, and seems to match the data structure in your screenshot. It might be good to debug the problem locally to find out more.  So place a breakpoint on the `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {`, run in the debugger until it hits that line, and then check the value of each variable before stepping to the next line. When you do this, which line/variable is the first that doesn't match your expectation?